# How to make "links" to local files work in a webapp?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a web-based (well - local network based) app that acts as a database for files on local drives - some sort of a catalogue that indexes the files and users can search and even comment on.

I would like that when I click on the link for a file in the app, (which probably would have a reference like "file:///drive/foldername/filename.docx"), the corresponding application opens with the file (in the example - word).

I have seen all sorts of posts pointing out security restrictions of modern browsers etc... so I think what I need to ensure is that somehow the right mime-type is transmitted (?) and then depending on the browser configuration, it will either ask to "download or open" the file...?

I might have to configure users' browser settings - that's fine, as said it's only locally affecting a handful of machines.

The database runs on ruby on rails but if there is something that I need to do in javascript, that's (hopefully) possible as well :)

Comment: Sounds like you should install a local web server too

Comment: ok I see I didn't really explain properly what I wanted to do. I have rephrased above - I am building a web app that acts as a database for files on a local file system. It shall serve as some sort of "document repository" for users that can be indexed, searched, etc.

Comment: File systems do not transmit mime types

Comment: I am not sure I know what you mean - the browser should transmit the mime type right? So is this all down to local browser configuration? At the moment, when I click a "file:///..." link - simply nothing happens?

Comment: No. The server transmits mime types. Then the browser will react to it. Mostly browsers will react to file extensions too unless the server overrides the mime type

Comment: You cannot have the file system set the "application/octet-stream" needed to download a file